# create a calculated column from comparing two columns based off a substring in the columns in sql

Tags: sql-server, string-comparison, calculated-columns

I have the following dataset

| Drawing Name | Line Number | Line Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PL00XXX-0705-1300 | **2"-MSH-0513-16-C1-**1 1/2"A | MATCH |
| PL00XXX-0705-1100 | **2"-MSH-0513-16-C1-**2"AE | DUPLICATE / HEAT TRACE |
| PL00XXX-0705-1300 | **2"-WWS-0513-15-C1-**0" | MATCH / NON ISO |
| PL00XXX-0705-1300 | **2"-WWS-0513-15-C1-**2"AE | MATCH / HEAT TRACE |
| PL00XXX-0705-1100 | **2"-WWS-0513-15-C1-**2"AE | DUPLICATE / HEAT TRACE |
| PL00XXX-0705-1300 | **2"-WWS-0513-17-C1-**2"AE | DO NOTHING |
| PL00XXX-0705-1100 | **2"-WWS-0513-18-C1-**2"AE | DO NOTHING |

The new calculated column I want to create is Line Details based if there are at LEAST 2 of a line number up to the last dash in the line number. IF there is not at least 2 of the same up to the last dash - do nothing.

The Line Details column shows Match if the drawing number would have 05-13 in it and the line number would have 0513 in it.

The Line Details column would show Duplicate if the drawing number had 05-13 in it and the line number had 0511 in it.

The Line Details column could ALSO show Heat Trace if the line number ends with an E.

The Line Details column could ALSO show Non Iso if the line number ends with 0".

The drawing number up to PL00XXX-07 is always the same per customer. it's what comes after that is important and how it's tied or not tied to the line number. At least 2 of the same line number means up to the - after C1. The amount of characters prior to that could be different, there could be a 2" line or a 1/2" line, but as long as the line number matches up to the C1- part of the line that represents 2 of the same.

IF this makes send PLEASE help. Greatly appreciated.

How can a query be written to only find duplicates up to the last hypen? I have the following line numbers:

```
2"-MSH-0513-16-S1-**1 1/2"A
2"-MSH-0513-16-S1-**2"AE
2"-MSH-0513-17-S1-**1 1/2"A
2"-MSH-0513-18-S1-**1 1/2"A
2"-FLW-0521-18-S1-**1"A
2"-FLW-0521-18-S1-**1"A
```

So the line numbers that I want to be shown in the list after the query is as follows:

```
2"-MSH-0513-16-S1-**1 1/2"A
2"-MSH-0513-16-S1-**2"AE
2"-FLW-0521-18-S1-**1"A
2"-FLW-0521-18-S1-**1"A
```

I know how to query a specific character count ONLY when the data is the exact same character count in the column. As you can see the character count can be different up the the last hyphen.

I have tried the following script:

```
select SUBSTRING(LINE_NUM_CONCAT_, 
                 1, 
                 regexp_instr(LINE_NUM_CONCAT_, 
                              '-', 
                              1, 
                              regexp_count(LINE_NUM_CONCAT_, 
                              '-')
                  ) - 1)
FROM  PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
```

but regex_count is not a recongnized built-in function name???

PLEASE help.

Comment: Please present you sample data clearly using the table markdown tools provided by the editor; your description and data is *not* clear - what is "drawing number"? do you mean "Drawing Name"? Much more clarity is needed about your data and its formatting.

Comment: *if there are at LEAST 2 of a line number up to the last dash in the line number* what does this mean? What constitutes "at least 2"? Your sample data does not appear to have anything that meets this requirement as you have data in the derived column for every row.

Comment: I apologize that I didn't provide enough clarity for you. I mean Drawing Number, it is the number of the drawing. The drawing number up to PL00XXX-07 is always the same per customer. it's what comes after that is important and how it's tied or not tied to the line number.  At least 2 of the same line number means up to the - after C1. The amount of characters prior to that could be different, there could be a 2" line or a 1/2" line, but as long as the line number matches up to the C1- part of the line that represents 2 of the same. Does this help at all? Again I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: Thanks - it would help if you could include some examples where this wasn't the case - ie, some "do nothing" rows, and also edit your question so everything relevant is in one place, not spread out on the comments.

Comment: You already know how to extract the "05-13" piece of [Drawing Name] from your previous question. Similar logic can be applied to the equivalent bit of [Line Number]. So if you add those computed columns, seems like this becomes MUCH simpler.

Comment: I have edited my question to include all the other details from the comment section plus "do nothing" lines.  I'm still thinking over the similar logic you speak about on computed columns.  I'm new to sql for my job and depending on what my workload is I can go weeks between using sql.  It takes longer for the light bulb to turn on. I'm unsure on how to do the part will there is at least 2 of the line numbers up to the dash and then how to add the correct if statement.

Comment: To Smor or anyone else, if you could provide an example for me that would be great. I have figured out how to get the characters after the last hyphen in a script but how to do that only when there at least two lines up to that last hyphen is where I'm stuck. I can show where there are duplicates of the entire column itself but not able to figure out how to write the script to show duplicates up to the last hyphen. I will edit the question to include this.

Comment: `regexp_instr` and `regexp_count` are `Oracle` function. It is not available in `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CASE` expression to evaluate your condition and return the string accordingly and concatenate all as one string

to check for duplicates use window function `count(*) over (partition by ...)`

```
select [Drawing Name], [Line Number],
   [Line Details] =
   case when count(*) over (partition by line) < 2
        then 'DO NOTHING'
        else
            case when [Drawing Name] like '%05-13%' 
                 and  [Line Number]  like '%0513%'
                 then 'MATCH'
                 else ''
                 end
          + case when [Drawing Name] like '%05-11%' 
                 and  [Line Number]  like '%0513%'
                 then 'DUPLICATE'
                 else ''
                 end            
          + case when right([Line Number], 1) = 'E'
                 then '/ HEAT TRACE'
                 when right([Line Number], 2) = '0"'
                 then '/ NON ISO'
                 else ''
                 end
         end
from PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES p
     cross apply
     (
        select line = left([Line Number], 
                           len([Line Number]) - charindex('-', reverse([Line Number]))
                          )
     ) l
where p.[Drawing Name] like 'PL00528%'
```

---

I have reorganized the query and using `APPLY()` operator to compute the various value. You can add the `WHERE` condition to exclude the `NO NOTHING` lines.

```
select *,
       case when line_count < 2
            then 'DO NOTHING'
            else
        m.match
        + duplicate         
        + case when right([Line Number], 1) = 'E'
               then '/ HEAT TRACE'
               when right([Line Number], 2) = '0"'
               then '/ NON ISO'
               else ''
               end
               end
from   (
           select *, line_count =  count(*) over (partition by line)
           from   PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES 
                  cross apply
                  (
                      select line = left([Line Number], 
                                         len([Line Number]) - charindex('-', reverse([Line Number])))
                  ) l
           where  [Drawing Name] like 'PL00528%'
       ) p
       cross apply
       (
           select match = case when [Drawing Name] like '%05-13%' 
                               and  [Line Number] like '%0513%'
                               then 'MATCH'
                               else ''
                               end  
       ) m
       cross apply
       (
           select duplicate = case when [Drawing Name] like '%05-11%' 
                                   and  [Line Number] like '%0513%'
                                   then 'DUPLICATE'
                                   else ''
                                   end 
       ) d
where  p.line_count >= 2  -- exclude the do nothing lines
```

Comment: This community is worth it's weight in gold for people like me. Learning SQL on the fly because my job now requires me to.  That filled out the line details exactly like I wanted it to.  Since you obviously know SQL very well is there a way to add to the query to show more columns than just line details? like col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5?  Lastly is there a way to add a where clause so only the drawing names that start with PL00528 come up in the results??? Thanks again........much appreciated!

Comment: you can add any additional columns you need in the `select` clause like 'select col1, col2 ....' . Edited the answer to include these. Also please do remember to accept the answer with the tick

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the answer, this is great! Last question on this topic, Is there a way to take out the lines where the line details = "do nothing"? So if there is not a duplicate of the line up to the last hyphen it doesn't show up in the results?? If not this is amazing and incredibly helpful. I wish I could double accept the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind on the removing the "do nothing" rows, I need them in there, sorry.

Comment: just in case that you changed your mind, you can enclosed the query as a `CTE` and then add a `WHERE` clause to exclude it